# Slow response when querying unicode (non ascii) characters in sybase

Tags: sql, sap-ase, tibco-ems

Query 1: `Select * from table where fieldname = 'abc'`

Query 2: `Select * from table where fieldname = 'XYï¿½'`

- My query 1 executes in 150mS
- My query 2 executes  in 5000mS

Both return zero results (`abc` and `XYï¿½` do not exist in database).

Once I run query 2 and then rerun my query 1, query 1 starts taking longer time if it is run in same session (around 2000ms instead of earlier 150ms)

My fieldname is indexed (non-clustered index).

I am using Adaptive Server Enterprise/12.5.4

I tried to do a show plan for both. Both show same results.

My worries:

1. Why queries with non ascii characters should take more time ? Is that something to do with indexes?
2. Running query 2 should not impact my query 1 response time. Any ways to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What does the table look like please, with indexes? And how does `Select fieldname  from table where fieldname = 'whatever'` perform?

Answer (score 1):

I found issue to my problem. TIBCO EMS does some changes to unicode chars(non ascii) which causes query plan in sybase to change to some non optimized query plan. When using prepared statements in Java query plan is cached ,as a result all future queries become slow.